# is it possible to extract the audio stream from an instance of class AudioClip in java

Tags: java, audio, java-8, mp3

I wrote a short player with command line arguments for mp3 files. Now I would like to access the amplitude data but there seems to be no possibility to get the audio data directly from the AudioClip class in javafx. The solution with mp3si from javazoom seems not to be state of the art, as it is already 9 years old and java has changed considerably over this time.

```
//lots of imports should appear here.
//
public class PlayingSound extends Application{
    protected List<String> files=null;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
       for(String soundfile : files) {
           AudioClip sound = 
             new AudioClip(new File(soundfile).toURI().toString());
       sound.play();
       while( sound.isPlaying() ) try { 
           Thread.sleep(100);
       } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
       }
   }
   Platform.exit();
}

@Override
public void init(){
    files = getParameters().getRaw();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: The Java Sound API used by mp3spi and javazoom is still current.

Comment: JavaFX is designed to be a black box communicating with Java through a limited API, not allowing anything that hasn’t been offered explicitly. Not only is there no way to get the audio data out, there’s also no way of getting data in—unless the source happens to be one of the supported URI types (i.e. no Java `InputStream`, no pipe, no extensible provider mechanism, etc). So if you decide to drop a working solution, just because it is nine years old, in other words, has reliably worked the last nine years, you have to live with JavaFX’s “state of the art”, which seems to be inflexibility×3.

Comment: Thanks so far. I will now use mp3spi.